# Networking commands doesn't work; what should I do?

Tags: networking

Commands I tried on Ubuntu Server 12.04:

```
#sudo /etc/init.d/networking start

Rather than invoking init scripts through `/etc/init.d`, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service networking start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start networking
networking stop/waiting


#service networking status
networking stop/waiting

#service networking start
networking stop/waiting
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? here isn't so much need to run these scripts manually. WHat ist the content of '/etc/network/interfaces'?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the network up with a static IP by using `ifconfig`  when you are connecting directly to your server. For example:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up 192.168.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

After, check with:

```
service networking status
```